# What is more powefull between a stored procedure and a view?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a project in which I have to interact with two databases.
One, the main and a second one who contains identities and rights of users..
So I made a view in the main with informations I need from the second one, very practical!

A Colleague this morning says to me that is more speedy and powerful (For the return) to use stored procedure in which I aim the second database directly without the view step.

Is it really the case? views are really practical because of the retrieve only data's I need but if perf's are not the same I will change for stored procedures..

Thanks for all answers..

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL-Server Performance:  What is faster, a stored procedure or a view?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1603853/sql-server-performance-what-is-faster-a-stored-procedure-or-a-view)

Comment: Sorry it seems it is an exact duplicate, sorry again..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NO, this seems completely incorrect.

The view can easily be used to join in other selects, where as with the stored procedure you will first have to insert the results into a temp/variable table.

Stored Procedures are as they are called used for more procedural coding.

Answer (score 3):

Don't just change stuff wily nily because someone says x is faster.

**Always**  profile before optimizing.

- Figure out where the bottlenecks in your application are.
- Fix those that have the largest impact on total perfomance first.
- Rinse and repeat.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is an answer to general question which is faster -- view or stored procedure other then **It depends** :).

If current solution is too slow (and I can imagine that checking user privileges is bottleneck) I would use both view and stored procedure.

**Materialized view** can help to aggregate data from various tables and well written **stored procedure** (with good query plan) helps to access view quickly.