# Any advantage using stored proc over a view?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored proc that performs a fairly complex SELECT statement. The stored proc accepts to params which are used in the query:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetConnections]
    @equipmentId int,
    @equipmentPortNum int
AS
    SELECT ..SELECT QUERY HERE..
END
```

I'm considering changing this to a view, and just filtering the view when I call it:

```
SELECT * from ConnectionsView Where EquipmentID = XXX and EquipmentPortNum = YYY
```

My question is: Is there any advantage of one over the other - esp wrt performance?

Since I will be calling the view from an ORM, the query will have parametised filter options and result in a cached execution plan, meaning (unless I'm wrong) that the stored proc won't be any more performant over the view - is this correct?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is more powefull between a stored procedure and a view?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4507399/what-is-more-powefull-between-a-stored-procedure-and-a-view)

Comment: Why not a UDF, since that seems to be what you're describing (a single select that needs to be parameterised)? Unless your ORM doesn't support them...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL-Server Performance: What is faster, a stored procedure or a view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1603853/sql-server-performance-what-is-faster-a-stored-procedure-or-a-view)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Duplicate.. A question asked by myself [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4507399/what-is-more-powefull-between-a-stored-procedure-and-a-view)

And another one [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1603853/sql-server-performance-what-is-faster-a-stored-procedure-or-a-view) asked by Roberto Sebestyen

I hope you'll find answer in these ones..